# How do I write a transaction for this case in AWS Redshift?

Tags: transactions, amazon-redshift

I'll describe the scenario first, as I might be overcomplicating the issue and if so, I'll just delete the question.

I am running a script that re-creates a table once a day. Due to the nature of the creation, the existing table has to be dropped and then the new table created. The process is basically like so:

- Execute the `CREATE TABLE AS` query and give table a placeholder name.
- `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS` the existing table.
- `ALTER TABLE RENAME` the newly created table.

However, part of the requirement is that if there are errors in dropping or renaming, I should be able to rollback the drop and still retain the newly-created "temporary" table. Obviously, I have to have a transaction.

How do I write the complete script, though? I was thinking something like...

```
CREATE TABLE target_temp AS SELECT * FROM src;
BEGIN;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS target;
ALTER TABLE target_temp RENAME TO target
COMMIT;
```

Or should I move `BEGIN;` to before the `CREATE TABLE`? If I understand correctly, by doing that, even the create command will be rolled back if there are errors in the drop/rename, right? Because this is not what is required.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your reasoning is correct.

Since Redshift supports transactional DDL statements, it will work as expected. I mean everything inside a failed transaction will be rolled back.

To be honest... the presented requirement  doesn't seem to have any sense. What could be the reason for keeping a temporary table?

For me the correct approach is making the `CREATE TABLE` part of the transaction.

Comment: Accepting this answer and +1. I know that this was fairly simple, but I had to be careful. Yes, I agree with you as well. However, I barely have any input into how the business requires its processes to behave. Since there is a chance that the tables are checked each day, I guess this will work fine. A foreseeable problem, though, is if the drop/rename fails and the temp table persists to the next day, which will surely cause an error when re-created. However, a check against `pg_table_def` will avoid this. And this is where I must admit that the entire process we've conjured is convoluted. :)